# Seleccción de registros diferentes agrupados por minimo

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día, el motivo de mi pregunta es debido a que no puedo realizar un select con los resultados deseados, lo que intento hacer es crear un columna en convinacion con dos diferentes columnas y que su contenido sea solo los no repetidos, pero agrupados por el mínimo de una tercer columna, como está la tabla es de como se ve en la siguiente imagen.

[image: tabla inicio]

Lo que quiero lograr es la consulta que me devuelva un resultado como el siguiente.

[image: resultado]

En cuanto a la primer columna "code_AB" la puedo obtener de la así:

```
select 
    distinct case when code_A is null or code_A = '' then code_B else code_A end code_AB
from 
    My_Table
```

Pero en mi segunda columna de resultados no puedo obtener el solo el mínimo por el código "abc1" el cual sería 1 y el mínimo del código "1opi4" que sería 10.

Puede que sea algo muy simple y le este dando muchas vueltas, agradecería mucho su apoyo, de ante mano gracias por cualquier ayuda que me puedan proporcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Si es que entendí bien, deseas generar la segunda tabla a partir de la primera, entonces la consulta para ello es la siguiente:

```
SELECT CONCAT(code_A,code_B) AS code_AB, MIN(number) as number
FROM My_Table
GROUP BY CONCAT(code_A,code_B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo aquí te deje un ejemplo de lo que necesitas.

```
DECLARE @HelpTable TABLE(
Code_A VARCHAR(50),
Code_B VARCHAR(50),
Number int
)

INSERT INTO @HelpTable VALUES('abc1',NULL,1),
('abc1',NULL,2),
('abc1',NULL,3),
('abc1',NULL,4),
('abc1',NULL,5),
('abc1',NULL,6),
('abc1',NULL,7),
('abc1',NULL,8),
('1OPI4',NULL,10),
('1OPI4',NULL,11),
('1OPI4',NULL,12),
('1OPI4',NULL,13),
('1OPI4',NULL,14),
('1OPI4',NULL,15),
('1OPI4',NULL,16),
('1OPI4',NULL,17),
(NULL,'MGA',9),
(NULL,'5624',18)

--EL COALESCE Si viene null toma el siguiente si no los tineen en null si no como '' entonces si usarias el CASE
SELECT COALESCE(Code_A,Code_B) AS CodeA_B,CASE WHEN ISNULL(Code_A,'')='' THEN Code_B ELSE Code_A END AS SinCoalesce, MIN(Number) AS Number
FROM @HelpTable
GROUP BY Code_A,Code_B
ORDER BY MIN(Number)
```

Y aqui un ejemplo funcionando.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9f432b2608f7aedd811537aeb55df97d